# What does dirAtten value mean in Kajiya-Kay Model?

Tags: rendering, hlsl, cg

In the [hair rendering slide](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/Scheuermann_HairRendering.pdf) developed by Sheuermann at ATI at GDC 2004, I found code like this:

```
float StrandSpecular (float3 T, float3 V, float3 L, float exponent)
{
    float3 H = normalize(L + V);
    float dotTH = dot(T, H);
    float sinTH = sqrt(1.0 - dotTH*dotTH);
    float dirAtten = smoothstep(-1.0, 0.0, dot(T, H));
    return dirAtten * pow(sinTH, exponent);
}
```

I truly have no idea of the value dirAtten mean, what does this exactly mean in this shading model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I regard this `dirAtten` as one attenuation coeffecient and it controls the range of the lighting you can see.